# VBA Display Chart In New Worksheet & Delete if it Already Exists

Tags: excel, vba

I'm wanting to display a chart in a new worksheet and have it get deleted if it already exists. I'm pretty (okay maybe just a little) sure I've got the code right but have a feeling something is wrong with either the placement or something I'm missing completely. Here is my code and a picture of the spreadsheet I'm working with:

```
Sub HistoricalDemand()
For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name = "Demand Line Chart" Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Sheets("Demand Line Chart").Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End
End If
Next

ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet, Name:="Demand Line Chart"

Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "[$-en-US]mmm-yy;@"

Range("A:A,E:E").Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(332, xlLineMarkers).Select
' Try With command here
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("A:A,E:E")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
Selection.TickLabels.Orientation = 70
Selection.MajorTickMark = xlNone
With ActiveChart
    .Axes(xlCategory).Select
    .Axes(xlCategory).MajorUnit = 2
    .ChartTitle.Select
    .ChartTitle.Text = "Historical Demand"
    .SetElement (msoElementLegendRight)
Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Historical Demand"
With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 17).ParagraphFormat
    .TextDirection = msoTextDirectionLeftToRight
    .Alignment = msoAlignCenter
End With
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Logic Error here: `If ws.Name = "Demand Line Chart" Then ...
        End
        End If` You issue is that `End` on its own stops execution of the Sub.. remove it

Comment: Use `Exit For` instead of `End` in the `For Each ... Next` loop.